# REST call for bringing browser to foreground via selenium web driver

Tags: rest, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to automate my browser.
I want to bring my browser to foreground if it is in background or minimized.

For minimized state, maximize rest call is running fine. And bring browser to foreground

```
POST /session/:sessionId/window/:windowHandle/maximize
```

But if browser is already maximized and is in background, it fails.

Their is call for focus, but that too just sets the focus internally, and do not bring browser to front.

I didn't find any rest call which brings the browser to foreground.

Using [JW protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol):

Answer (score 0):

Store the window handle first in a variable, and then use it to go back to the window later on.

//Store the current window handle

String currentWindowHandle = this.webDriver.getWindowHandle();

You should be able to do this with

driver.SwitchTo().Window("//name of the window");

and that will bring whatever window you want into focus.